# Magento 2 - How to sell items separately or as a set?

Tags: magento2, product, qty, product-type

We currently have a lot of items that we sell either as a full set or as individual items.

For example say we have a product - Green Marbles. The individual sizes are small,med,large. Or a full set includes 1xLarge, 2xMed, 4xSmall.

Ideally what I would like is to have a single product page that offers:

Customer can edit Qty's for all individual items

Customer Can select - Full Set.

i.e.

Large............qty ?

Med..............qty ?

Small............qty ?

Full Set.........qty ?

I could set up Full Set as a simple product but that means stock qtys would be a nightmare. Is there a way to set this up in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Create a grouped product. Grouped product with configurable products meets your requirement

Comment: Grouped Product can't sell full set. Unless I can't work it out. If you buy a fulls set it would be cheaper say full price -20%.